# Help with a Core Data Concept

Tags: iphone, core-data

Just want to confirm that I have this correct, and would like to see some sample code.

When I want to add a new record to Core Data, I create a new instance of an NSManagedObject subclass, correct? Then what? (Some sample code would be welcome.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `moc` is your managed object context and `obj` is your newly created managed object,

```
[moc insertObject:obj];

// save to persistent store
NSError *error;
if (![moc save:&error]) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just found a basic Core Data video from Apple. Can't believe I missed it!